# before_action :setup equivalent in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to to DRY up this controller:

```
defmodule Xyz.ExampleController do
  use Xyz, :controller

  alias XyZ.Shops

  def a(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    product = Shops.get_product!(id)
    tax = product.price * 0.15

    ... 

    render(conn, "a.html", foobar: foobar, product: product)
  end

  def b(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    product = Shops.get_product!(id)
    tax = product.price * 0.15

    ... 

    render(conn, "b.html", foobar: foobar, tax: tax)
  end

  def c(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
    product = Shops.get_product!(id)
    tax = product.price * 0.15

    ... 

    render(conn, "c.html", foobar: foobar)
  end  

end
```

Every function starts with this part:

```
    product = Shops.get_product!(id)
    tax = product.price * 0.15
```

In the Ruby on Rails world I'd put it a method to be called with `before_action :setup` to DRY the controller.

What is the best way to achieve a DRY up of this in Phoenix?

Comment: You can use a plug -> https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/plug.html, and I beg you, don't put business logic into the framework modules.

Comment: This logic shouldn't be in a Controller IMO. If it were me, I would define a function which works like this: `{product, tax} = Shops.get_product_and_tax!(id)` and call that from each action.

Comment: Than I'll do that. I thought it would be cleaner to have it in a plug. But I'm happy to keep the one line of code in each action.

Comment: @wintermeyer You can do both, you can create a plug which would call this function and set the data for all required actions, no duplication required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the `action/2` controller method. From the [controller docs](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#module-controllers-are-plugs):

> As controllers are plugs, they implement both init/1 and call/2, and
>   it also provides a function named action/2 which is responsible for
>   dispatching the appropriate action after the plug stack (and is also
>   overridable).

In the book `Programming Phoenix` Chris McCord uses this action to put a common parameter to all the controller functions like this:

```
def​ action(conn, _) ​do​
​  apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn), [conn, conn.params, conn.assigns.current_user])
​end​
```

So every action like `index/2` is now `index/3` and has the current user as third parameter.

Maybe this could help you?

Comment: I don't think using this approach is better than a plug, it's less flexible and doesn't give any advantage over a plug in this situation.